# Using an aggregate in a Django model's property

Tags: django, django-models, django-aggregation

### Schema Description

[image]

A project could have multiple project items, and a project item could have multiple acquisition costs. For example, capital project #1 contains two project items:

1. Qty. 1 production equipment purchased

   - One acquisition cost of $5,000 for the purchasing the equipment from a supplier
2. Qty. 1 test fixture constructed by staff

   - Twelve $1,000 purchases each for total acquisition costs of $12,000.

The production equipment might have only one cost associated with purchasing it. However, the test fixture could have multiple costs associated with constructing it.

### Desire

I want to be able to determine the total acquisition costs for each item, and I want to be able to determine the total acquisition costs for each project. Based on the above example:

- Item 1 total acquisition costs = $5,000
- Item 2 total acquisition costs = $12,000
- Capital project total acquisition costs = $17,000

### Questions

1. Should the `total_acquisition_costs` be calculated using Django's aggregates or saved as a `DecimalField` on the `Project` and `ProjectItem` models?
2. Should I create a `total_acquisition_costs` property for the `ProjectItem` and `Project` models? My gut feel is yes to create a property.

   My gut feel is to calculate the values using aggregates, so as to avoid database denormalization. Specifically, I'm leaning toward using Django's aggregate `Sum` function to create a `total_acquisition_costs` property. However, I'm not grokking how to put an aggregate on a model as a property so that it just returns a value instead of a dictionary.

### Current Code

**Note:** My current code does not use Django's aggregate capabilities, but it works.

```
class ProjectItem(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(CapExProject)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    @property
    def total_acquisition_costs(self):
        acquisition_costs = self.acquisitioncost_set.only(
                'amount')
        total_acquisition_costs = 0
        for acquisition_cost in acquisition_costs:
        total_acquisition_costs += acquisition_cost.amount
        return total_acquisition_costs
```

Comment: What did you use to generate the class diagram?

Comment: @Tom: I used OmngiGraffle Professional on OS X to create the drawings with the Django drawing stencil downloaded from Graffletopia.com.

Answer (score 14):

I like your idea of using Sum but making it a property. Something like this should work:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    @property
    def total_acquisition_costs(self):
        return AcquisitionCost.objects.filter(item__project=self).aggregate(total=Sum("amount"))["total"]

class ProjectItem(models.Model):
    @property
    def total_acquisition_costs(self):
        return self.acquisitioncost_set.aggregate(total=Sum("amount"))["total"]
```